# How do I get the specific cell for a navigation button?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I want to get the tableView's cell but I can't get the `indexPath.row` as I'm not in the tableview class. I have written the code which I believe would work if I wrote but doesn't work in the button. I want to get this for a navigation button. I have seen some similar suggestions but for when the button is in the actual cell.

FYI it is not a `tableViewController` but a `tableView` included in a `UIViewController`.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
@IBAction func addMeal(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    var newMeal = selectedMeal!

    // Checks to see if the specific ingredient is ticked (checkmarked)
    if cell.accessoryType != UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark {
        // If not then it removes it from the new meal's ingredients
        newMeal.mealsIngredients.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    }

    // Adds the new meals to an array
    myMeals.insert(newMeal, at: indexPath.row)

    // Segues away      
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "MealDetailViewController", sender: self)
}
```

[image: This shows what I want to do]

Comment: An entire view controller with navigation bar is inside a tableview cell?

Comment: @Shades a viewController which is embedded in a navigation controller has a tableview inside of it, but inside of the cell.